# is there any api end point or database query to get the application points data(app points) of maximo?

Tags: maximo

I need to find the api end point or query to get the application points in maximo application

I tried searching for it but i am unable to find anything.

It would be great if anyone of you could answer this question.

Even knowing about any database query would also be helpful.